# Kubernetes kubectl cluster-info gives connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I'm new to the kubernetes and
I'm using ubuntu 20.04 aarch64 remote server,
`kubectl version` command gives an error
`The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

I don't know whats going wrong.
Thanks!

I'm following these two resources

https://blog.knoldus.com/how-to-create-deployment-using-kubernetes-python-client/

and second one is

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/23/get-started-with-kubernetes-using-python/

I have tried with yaml file with some configuration,

Comment: Your `~/.kube/config` file isn't configured to point to the remote cluster.  The linked question has a couple of examples for GKE and Minikube.